# SQL multiple columns in greater than expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, comparison, where-clause

Saw the following SQL relating to paging results with cursors and am having trouble finding more information on how part of it works:

```
SELECT b.* FROM books b
WHERE (b.name, id) > (select b2.name, b2.id
                      from books b2
                      where b2.id = ?
                      )
ORDER BY b.name;
```

What happens when you have multiple columns within a single comparison expression? I haven't found any other examples of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comparisons are made as "tuples", from left to right.  So, the first value is compared in each tuple, then the next is compared.  So:

- `(1, 2) > (1, 1)`  --> true
- `(1, 1) > (1, 1)`  --> false
- `(2, 1) > (2, 2)`  --> false
- `(2, 1) > (1, 10)` --> true

Comment: Is there a name for this syntax?

Comment: Quote from mysql reference:

For row comparisons, (a, b) > (x, y) is equivalent to:
(a > x) OR ((a = x) AND (b > y))

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than-or-equal